# Send image data with AJAX request

Tags: python, ajax

I have this working code in Python

```
reponse = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=open('image.jpg','rb'))
```

I need to do the exact same thing with AJAX, just in this case image is base64 encoded

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST', 
        username: username, 
        password: password, 
        data: atob(image), 
        url: url,
        success: function(response) { ... }});
```

also tried

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'image.jpg');
fd.append('data', atob(image));
$.ajax({type: 'POST', 
        username: username, 
        password: password, 
        data: fd,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        url: url,
        success: function(response) { ... }});
```

I can't seem to get it working. The call itself is a success, but the API on the other side does not seem to be getting the image. What am I missing ?

Comment: The server will have to decode the Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently contentType needed to be set manually to a value corresponding to the data. It's working now with the proper contentType.